# Factor $x^5+x^2+1$ into irreducible polynomials in $Z[x]$

Tags: number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

So here is my question: i would like to determine if whether or not the polynomial $x^5+x^2+1$ in $Z[x]$ is irreducible and if not then find the factors.

I tried a lot to find it. I really think it is already irreducible but I don't know how to prove it.

I tried Eisenstein's criteria which doesn't work here, I tried to check this criteria also after changing $x$ as $ax+b$ but everything I check was too complicated.

I tried for the modulus with prime numbers of $Z$, and I'm not sure of my following argument:

The polynomial $\mod 2$ stays $x^5+x^2+1$. 
But if $x$ is odd then $x^5$ and $x^2$ are odd too. Then the polynomial is given by $1+1+1=3=1 \mod 2$ which is irreducible (not sure if I have the right to say that).

And if $x$ is even, then $x^5$ and $x^2$ are even too. The polynomial is thus given by $0+0+1=1 \mod 2$ which is irreducible.

Hence the polynomial is irreducible $\mod 2$ and since it's a monic polynomial it implies it is irreducible in $Z[x]$

Is my argument correct?
If not if you have any clue please I would like to have some :)

Thank you and good night!

Comment: All you've shown is that the polynomial does not have a root, modulo $2$. That doesn't mean that the polynomial is irreducible. For example, $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$. Indeed, it is easy to use the rational root test to see that any rational root of $x^5+x^2+1=0$ must be $\pm 1$, so we know there is no linear factor in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your argument that $\bar f=x^5+x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$ is not valid. As Thomas Andrews has noted, you’ve only shown that $\bar f$ has no linear factors. Fortunately, there is only one irreducible quadratic polynomial over $\Bbb F_2$, and that is $x^2+x+1$. But you easily check that when you divide this into $\bar f$, the quotient is $x^3+x^2$ and the remainder is $1$, so $\bar f$ has no linear nor quadratic factor, and therefore is irreducible.

As a result, your polynomial over $\Bbb Z$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answers!

Comment: @Lubin: I have one doubt.In mod p test,while checking linear factors of a polynomial is it enough to show that if we divide that by polynomial by irreducible polynomial in $Z_p$ and if remainder is non-zero then can we conclude that polynomial is irreducible?

Comment: @ASHWINISANKHE, I’m not at all sure what your question is. Let $f$ be a polynomial over a field $k$, let’s say the degree of $f$ is $n$. To check for irreducibility, we must try if $g|f$ for all $k$-polynomials of degree $m$ with $2m\le n$. If any one such $g$ divides, then $f$ is reducible. It is not enough to check that $f$ has no roots in $k$, unless $n\le3$, because indivisibility by a linear is equivalent to having no root in $k$.

Comment: @Lubin:In above question,To check irreducibility of $f$ we first take mod 2 of $f$ then we checked that it has no roots in $\Bbb Z _2$ .To check whether $\overline f$ can be factories?For that you take irreducible polynomial in  $\Bbb Z _2$  and divide $\overline f$.If it is completely divisible we are saying $ f$ is reducible if not then it is irreducible.Is this much sufficient to check irreducibility?Why?

Comment: I’m awfully sorry, but I can’t understand what you say. If $f\in\Bbb F_2[X]$ is reducible and of degree five, then it has a factor of degree one or two. Contrapositive: if it has no factor of degree either one or two, then it is irreducible. Period.

Answer (score 2):

> So here is my question: i would like to determine if whether or not the polynomial x5+x2+1 in Z[x] is irreducible and if not then find the factors.

Lubin already addressed the issue in your approach, let me show an alternative way to see it is actually irreducible using [**Cohn's irreducibility criterion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion): The $f(2)=37$ is a prime, and since the coefficients are non-negative and less than $2$, $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Another way to look at this criterion is that the coefficients of the polynomial written in base $2$ give a prime, i.e. $(100101)_2=37.$

Comment: A downvoter, is there something wrong with the answer?

Comment: Cute. I tend to forget about Cohn's criterion. May be because checking that an integer is a prime is not really easier than checking that a binary polynomial is irreducible? Admittedly many of us have had a reason to memorize lists of small primes, irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb{F}_2[x]$ not so much.